# RegEx help please - embedded double-quote in quoted string

Tags: regex

I've been searching, browsing stackoverflow RegEx solutions until I'm buggy-eyed.

I have a third-party solution that is delivering a "tab delimited text file", but I have determined whatever is generating this file is embedding double-quotes (and not even escaping them) - and I wonder if its possible to scrub these errors out of the file with RegEx  (I am using FNR on the file prior to import).

Each row of data contains 14 columns, tab-delimited, with double-quotes around each field as expected.  All of the defects are occurring in field 2 or field 10 (not first or last field), because these are training courses - some instructors use names having double-quotes in the name itself - and this third-party report doesn't escape them.  I am hoping to catch the TAB before and after the correct quotation marks - and filter any internal erroneous double-quotes or escape them properly with \".

```
"......"    "ADC000000" "Being the "Best" you can be"   "2F8A776C"  "...."
"......"    "BBC555555" ""Golden Opportunity""  "8F4C3DEE"  "...."
```

desired output

```
"......"    "ADC000000" "Being the \"Best\" you can be" "2F8A776C"  "...."
"......"    "BBC555555" "\"Golden Opportunity\""    "8F4C3DEE"  "...."
```

or (whichever is easiest, and pretty fast the files have 220,000 rows in them and only 16-50 errors)

```
"......"    "ADC000000" "Being the Best you can be" "2F8A776C"  "...."
"......"    "BBC555555" "Golden Opportunity"    "8F4C3DEE"  "...."
```

sorry about the verbosity of this.  But I wanted the problem to be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the below regex to match `"` which are not preceeded by  tab or start of the line and not followed by a tab or the end of a line anchor.

```
(?<!\t|^)"(?!\t|$)
```

Then replace the matched `"` with `\\"`.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kJ5oL9/1)

Comment: Thanks Avinash for the quick response, this looks pretty close - but also picks up the quotes at both the beginning and end of every line.  Is there a way to avoid matching those case?

Comment: I might have spoke too soon, I was using debuggex.com to try and figure it out myself - but I followed your demo link and it doesn't have this issue.  Give me a short while to figure out how to feed this to FNR.

Comment: This worked smashingly Avinash, thanks.  It immediately found 58 errors in my 220,000 rows (a bunch I had missed) - to make it work properly with FNR I changed it to:
   (?<!\t|^)"(?!\t|\r|$)
because for some reason FNR was matching all the end-of-line double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can match any quote that is both preceded and followed by characters that are not tabs:

```
s/([^\t])"([^\t])/$1\\"$2/g
```

(The $1 and $2 put the matched preceding and following character back in the substituted string. Exact syntax may vary depending on your regex engine.)

If your regex engine supports it, you can use lookbehind and lookahead to make it a bit simpler:

```
s/(?<!\t)"(?!\t)/\\"/g
```

Comment: FNR apparently uses the .NET RegEx per docs which is similar to Perl 5 RegEx.  Which engine uses this s/ /g format, maybe I can convert it to Perl and try it.

Comment: `s/(PATTERN)/(REPLACEMENT)/g` is Perl's notation for searching for the regex `(PATTERN)` and replacing it by `(REPLACEMENT)` - so that would be equivalent to a call to e.g. `replace(string, '(PATTERN)', '(REPLACEMENT)')`. (The `g` at the end signifies using all matches in the string, not just the first one.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I cannot upvote your answer (too new to forums I guess), but if I was using pure Perl (instead of FNR which has separate find and replace inputs) this would be what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Split on the tabs then strip off leading and trailing quotes:

```
line.split('\t').map(function(field) { return field.replace(/^"|"$/, ''); })
```

In general, it seems people are trying to do to much regexps that could be more easily done with other approaches such as splitting and scanning.

Comment: I am definitely guilty of trying to do something with RegExp that might have a better solution if I ran some type of processing script.  This is Python, correct?   Maybe my time would be best spent learning a really good string manipulation language - that I can run from windows batch -- is Python it?

Comment: If it's Python, you have to add the Python tag. (The above is JS, sorry.) Anyway, no you don't need a string manipulation language to split and match strings, all languages have those capabilities. Your time would be best spent learning the language you are coding in.